# Why is this loop being endless?

Tags: c++, loops, undefined-behavior

I have been programming for a long time and stumbled across something very weird.

Somewhere in my code I had the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
    if((i * 12391823) % 5 == 1){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have already tracked the problem down to this piece of code.
I am using CLion. When compiling a Debug build, the loop is not endless and finishes eventually after printing a few numbers.

Yet when building as Release, it seems to never exit the loop.

```
...
>>> 15968768
>>> 15968773
>>> 15968778
...
```

If `(i * 12391823)` is replaced with a different (smaller) number, this does not happen.

E.g. with `(i * 123)`, it does exit nicely:

```
...
>>> 482
>>> 487
>>> 492
...
```

---

I have also looked at the compile output which displayed the following:

```
warning: iteration 174 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   16 |         if((i * 12391823) % 5 == 1){
      |            ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I do wonder why this would lead to the loop not ending.
It seems to overflow, yet it is not supposed to change `i` and therefor end the loop at some point, right?

I am very happy for an explanation on this topic!

Greetings
FInn

Comment: try `12391823ULL` instead

Comment: that works. but why?

Comment: Perhaps you are reaching the limits of ```int```

Comment: I surely am, yet i am not so sure why the loop does not end

Comment: 512 * 12391823 = 6344613376 but `INT_MAX` = 2147483647

Comment: yeah  . /////////

Comment: @M.A I do know that but why would it lead to the loop not ending?

Comment: @FinnEggers integer overflow is UB, anything can happen.

Comment: its just that? thats very silly :D but thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at the assembler code produced ?

Comment: @FinnEggers from the C++11 Standard:

If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [...]

Comment: Also, @FinnEggers, I believe ULL is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide, much more memory for your ```i``` variable.

Comment: So I guess just avoiding undefined behaviour as much as possible is desired... :D

Comment: Yeah will stick with ULL then. Thank you

Comment: Well in a normal case ```int``` would be desired because it's unlikely you would reach ```INT_MAX```, and it's more memory-efficient. But you have a special use case that requires ```ULL```, so that's not desired, it's required... probably

Comment: just have tested it on 64-bit g++ and it's fine. so it's c-lion problems. number is less than 32bit. even for a numbers wider than 32 bits it should be auto handled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do wonder why this would lead to the loop not ending. It seems to overflow, yet it is not supposed to change i and therefor end the loop at some point, right?

The answer is "Undefined Behaviour is undefined". It can do anything. But, the fact that you get a warning from `aggressive-loop-optimizations` may hint at the reason why loop becomes endless. It is possible that compiler decides to modify your loop into

```
for(int i = 0; i < 512 * 12391823; i + 12391823){
    if(i % 5 == 1){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or maybe even

```
for(int i = 24783646; i < 512 * 12391823; i + 12391823 * 5){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Both options could act strangely when integer overflow happens.

---

The solution is to not get into Undefined Behaviour lands. You can do that for example by changing type of `i` from `int` to `unsigned long long`

```
for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < 512; i++)
```

Comment: that is interesting! Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: While this may be true, it is nevertheless a compiler bug. The loop exit expression is i < 512 and the range of i is known to the compiler and yet it is ignoring the fact that i will overflow through its optimisation and producing code that changes the semantics resulting in unforeseen behaviour. It should not be necessary to resort to using types that are possibly larger than the machine's native word size just to get valid code to work properly.

Comment: @PeterBall Assuming that `int` is 32-bit on OP's computer, this is not valid code. `i * 12391823` for `i == 511` results in an overflow, which means Undefined Behaviour. Compiler is allowed to absolutely anything with code that contains UB.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The undefined behaviour is limited to the `if` statement. The `for` statement is valid and should not be compromised by the comparatively minor bug in the `if` statement. Endless loops can be very serious, for example in embedded systems, for which C is the preferred language, these can adversely affect system stability and be very hard to track down. Particularly in a case such as this, which might involve a larger amount of code in the loop body possibly where the offending code is located somewhere else in an inlined function, it would be a bad day in the office.

Comment: @PeterBall Single Undefined Behaviour makes the behaviour of the whole program undefined. There is no guarantee whatsoever about the resulting program. Standard even mentions  explicitly that UB is allowed to affect code before it is present. It can even [travel back in time](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633). I understand your concerns, but UB is UB and it's perfectly valid compiler behaviour from standard point of view. It's programmer's fault either way.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting undefined behavior in the line:

```
if((i * 12391823) % 5 == 1){
```

This is because for i larger then 173 the multiplication result exceeds integer range.

When it comes to undefined behavior - you are at the liberty of the compiler. In optimized builds they tend to compile away some (even large) chunks of code in and around the expression which causes it. And as you just experienced - it may even spread to the code which by itself is correct (the exit condition in the for loop).

BTW integer overflow (as far as I know) causes undefined behavior only for signed integers, it is well defined for unsigned types (the result is truncated). You may want o try i of unsigned type (but this still MAY yield results which you didn't expect).

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer! I will accept it asap.

Comment: You're assuming a 32 bit `int`  (common in practice, but not guaranteed by the standard).    There are implementations with a 16 bit `int`, for which the line gives undefined behaviour when `i == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, the values generated in the loop, specifically this sub-expression:

```
(i * 12391823)
```

overflows for larger values of `i`. This results in undefined behaviour.

The issue is resolved by using a wider type for `i`, like `long long`.

---

Note: If you use an unsigned type, they will wrap around rather than overflow, if their max limit is exceeded.